# Spring Security # in URL

Tags: servlets, spring-security

I'm currently using a Preauthentication with Spring Security through an SSO solution, and was having a problem with #'s in the URL.  I noticed if you URL encode the #, the redirect would work correctly if the user was not logged in, so I wrote a filter that would look for URL encoded parameters, and decode them.  The problem is, now if you are logged in, it seems like the URL is being decoded, and my filter is never being touched.

This is a really confusing question, but I'll try to explain what I am seeing through how the requests are handled.

Not Logged In:
/%23/some/resource

Redirect to SSO:

SSO Redirects to:
/#/some/resource

This works well.

Logged In:
/%23/some/resource

:
/#/some/resource is the URI passed, so no rewrite needed, verified through debug logging that the URL is being passed through.

/%23/some/resource is returned to browser, 404 is returned.

Where I am getting confused is why it's decoding, then it seems to be re-encoding the URL after the filter-chain (maybe?)

Thanks for any help!